# React stateless component clearTimeout does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, cleartimeout

I'm having a issue with a component I've built.  One value (`inclVal`) must be larger than another (`exclVal`) if both are entered.  I wanted to run the function that handles this with a `setTimeout()` so that it wouldn't update for a second after the props stop changing to ensure it wouldn't change the value the user is entering while she is entering it.  To this end, I put in a `clearTimeout()` in an `else` block to prevent the function from executing if the props change so as to make it redundant.  The problem is that `clearTimeout()` isn't working for some reason and the update function is running whenever the `if` block is entered, even though the `else` block is being entered within the timeout interval.

The component is a stateless functional component and is using redux for state management.  I've read a bunch on how to make these things work, but nothing seems to be helping.  Any help is appreciated!

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import SelectPickerPulldown from '../../components/SelectPickerPulldown'
import TextInput from '../../components/TextInput'

import { odOptions } from '../../config/'
import { setODProperty } from '../../actions/odAnalyzerActions'
import { getConversion, getGreaterVal } from '../../utils/'

const InclusionExclusionOptions = ({  name,
                                      analysisPoint,
                                      paths,
                                      exclVal,
                                      exclUnit,
                                      inclVal,
                                      inclUnit,
                                      getVal,
                                      getUnit,
                                      setSafeInclVal,
                                    }) => {

  const disabled = analysisPoint !== null || paths ? false : true

  let inclEntryTimer = null

  const exclCompare = getConversion(exclUnit)(exclVal)
  const inclCompare = getConversion(inclUnit)(inclVal)

  if (exclVal > 0 && inclVal > 0 && exclCompare > inclCompare) {
    const safeInclVal = getGreaterVal(exclVal, exclUnit, inclUnit)
    console.log('entering timeout');
    inclEntryTimer = setTimeout( () => {
      console.log('dispatching timeout action');
      setSafeInclVal(safeInclVal)
    }, 1000)
  }
  else {
    console.log('clearing timeout');
    clearTimeout(inclEntryTimer)
    inclEntryTimer = null
  }


  return (
    <div className="form-group" >
      <h4>Inclusion/Exclusion Options</h4>
      <ul className={name}>
        <li className={`text-select-group ${disabled ? name + ' disabled' : name}`}>
          <p>Exclusion Radius</p>
          <div className="radius-setting">
            <TextInput
              type="number"
              name="exclVal"
              value={exclVal}
              onChange={getVal}
              />
            <SelectPickerPulldown
              value={'exclUnit'}
              options={odOptions.units}
              selected={exclUnit}
              getSelected={getUnit}
              />
          </div>
        </li>
        <li className={`text-select-group ${disabled ? name + ' disabled' : name}`}>
          <p>Inclusion Radius</p>
          <div className="radius-setting">
            <TextInput
              type="number"
              name="inclVal"
              value={inclVal}
              onChange={getVal}
              />
            <SelectPickerPulldown
              value={'inclUnit'}
              options={odOptions.units}
              selected={inclUnit}
              getSelected={getUnit}
              />
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

InclusionExclusionOptions.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  exclVal: PropTypes.number,
  exclUnit: PropTypes.string,
  inclVal: PropTypes.number,
  inclUnit: PropTypes.string,
  getVal: PropTypes.func,
  getUnit: PropTypes.func,
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const name = 'inclusion-exclusion-options'
  const { analysisPoint,
          paths,
          exclVal,
          exclUnit,
          inclVal,
          inclUnit } = state.odAnalyzerState

  return {
    name,
    analysisPoint,
    paths,
    exclVal,
    exclUnit,
    inclVal,
    inclUnit,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getUnit: option => dispatch(setODProperty(option)),
    getVal: (e, name) => dispatch(setODProperty({[name]: parseInt(e.target.value)})),
    setSafeInclVal: safeInclVal => dispatch(setODProperty({inclVal: safeInclVal}))
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps)(InclusionExclusionOptions)
```

Here is the updated code with a class component using `componentDidUpdate()`:

```
class InclusionExclusionOptions extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.inclEntryTimer = null
  }

  componentDidUpdate(props){
    const { exclVal,
            exclUnit,
            inclVal,
            inclUnit,
          } = this.props

    const exclCompare = getConversion(exclUnit)(exclVal)
    const inclCompare = getConversion(inclUnit)(inclVal)

    if (!!exclVal && !!inclVal && exclCompare > inclCompare) {
      const safeInclVal = getGreaterVal(exclVal, exclUnit, inclUnit)
      console.log('entering timeout')
      this.inclEntryTimer = setTimeout( () => {
        console.log('dispatching timeout action');
        this.props.setSafeInclVal(safeInclVal)
      }, 3000)
    }
    else {
      console.log('clearing timeout');
      clearTimeout(this.inclEntryTimer)
      this.inclEntryTimer = null
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { name,
            analysisPoint,
            paths,
            exclVal,
            exclUnit,
            inclVal,
            inclUnit,
            getVal,
            getUnit,
          } = this.props

    const disabled = analysisPoint !== null || paths ? false : true

    return (
      <div className="form-group" >
        <h4>Inclusion/Exclusion Options</h4>
        <ul className={name}>
          <li className={`text-select-group ${disabled ? name + ' disabled' : name}`}>
            <p>Exclusion Radius</p>
            <div className="radius-setting">
              <TextInput
                type="number"
                name="exclVal"
                value={exclVal}
                onChange={getVal}
                />
              <SelectPickerPulldown
                value={'exclUnit'}
                options={odOptions.units}
                selected={exclUnit}
                getSelected={getUnit}
                />
            </div>
          </li>
          <li className={`text-select-group ${disabled ? name + ' disabled' : name}`}>
            <p>Inclusion Radius</p>
            <div className="radius-setting">
              <TextInput
                type="number"
                name="inclVal"
                value={inclVal}
                onChange={getVal}
                />
              <SelectPickerPulldown
                value={'inclUnit'}
                options={odOptions.units}
                selected={inclUnit}
                getSelected={getUnit}
                />
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Per Brandon's suggestion, I was able to get the timeout cleared by simply clearing it before redeclaring it.  I broke out a clear timeout function as

```
  clearInclEntryTimer(){
    clearTimeout(this.inclEntryTimer)
    this.inclEntryTimer = null
  }
```

then called it at the top of the `if` block and in the `else` block.  That worked well.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You shouldn't be performing side effects like `setTimeout` inside of a render method (and a functional component is effectively _just_ a render method).  If you want to do something like that, this should really be a class component instead, and the behavior should be put in a component lifecycle method.

Answer (score 2):

The actual problem is that everytime your component renders, it generates a *new* instance of `inclEntryTimer` (and all other local variables) and so there's no way for a subsequent call to ever clear the timeout started in a previous call.

The conceptual problem is that your component is *stateful*, not *stateless*.  Your requirements are such that the component needs to track time as state (specifically the timer).  Change your stateless component to a traditional stateful component and you'll be able to store the timer id as a property of the class instance.  You can then use `componentDidUpdate(prevProps)` life cycle event to clear the timeout if the conditions are met.

Update:

Based on what you've tried, the real problem is that you aren't clearing the old timers on every prop change.  So think about what happens if the props change and you start a timer, the props change again and it is still higher so you start a 2nd timer and never clear the first, the props change again and you start a 3rd timer and so on.  Finally the props change and you stop the last timer.  But the first 5 timers are still running.  So you should clear the existing timer everytime you start a new one.

But if you step back from the problem slightly...you don't need to implement this pattern yourself.  What you are doing is something known as "debouncing".  So use someone else's debounce algorithm.

Here's how to do it with lodash:

```
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce';

export default class Component from React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
       this.correctValues(this.props);
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.correctValues(this.props);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        // prevent the debounced method from running after we unmount
        this._unmounted = true;
    }

    render() {
       return <div>...</div>;
    }

    // we use debounce to essentially only run this function 3000 ms after
    // it is called.  If it gets called a 2nd time, stop the first timer
    // and start a new one.  and so on.
    correctValues = debounce(props => {
        // make sure we are still mounted
        if (!this._unmounted) {
            // need to correct the values!
            if (props.a < props.b) {
                props.setCorrectValue(props.a);
            }
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: Ok, that was what I feared was happening, though even with a stateful, class component, I'm getting the same result using `componentWillReceiveProps()` and `setState()` to store the timer and then (theoretically) cancel it.  I don't seem to be able to cancel it in response to props changing.

Comment: Do your timeout logic in componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate.  Don't store the timer id in setState. Just store it as a field in the class. Other than that, show your updated code.

Comment: Thanks, just got to trying it now, the timeout is still not clearing.  I don't understand using `componentDidMount()` as I the timeout function to either run or be cleared as the props change.  Here is the code:

Comment: ```class InclusionExclusionOptions extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.inclEntryTimer = null
  }

  ```

Comment: ```componentDidUpdate(props){
    const { exclVal,
            exclUnit,
            inclVal,
            inclUnit,
          } = this.props

    const exclCompare = getConversion(exclUnit)(exclVal)
    const inclCompare = getConversion(inclUnit)(inclVal)

    if (!!exclVal && !!inclVal && exclCompare > inclCompare) {
      const safeInclVal = getGreaterVal(exclVal, exclUnit, inclUnit)
      console.log('entering timeout')
      this.inclEntryTimer = setTimeout( () => {
        this.props.setSafeInclVal(safeInclVal)
      }, 3000)
    }
```

Comment: `   else {
      clearTimeout(this.inclEntryTimer)
      this.inclEntryTimer = null
    }
  }`

Comment: Sorry for the terrible code formatting - not sure of the best way to reply with code.

Comment: Edit your question and put the code into the question